# YA book with Umbra organization

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I know it is about a boy and girl who have a strong connection. There is an organization called Umbra. Another girl is kind of a bad character who tempts the guy. I recall 4 books

Comment: This is a little sparse on details, is there anything else you can remember? When did you read it, and was it recent or old then? Any particular events that stick out?

Comment: Ive been trying to remember for the longest time. There was a good guy trying to help, and he had a pen that looked ordinary excpept for two buttons that when pressed together, shot out a lightning bolt. There are 2 other organizations too I think.

Comment: I remember the series, one of the main characters was female, her father was part of one of the organizations and helped give the male main character some kindof power. There were 3 Organizations, Umbra, The CIA and one other, and I seem to remember people kept getting kidnapped and escaping. The title was dark intentions, dark horizons, or something like that. Unfortunately that is all i can remember. I Read the books when i was in 6th or 7th grade, and they were on the accelerated reader list.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while trying to figure this book out myself! All I could remember was Umbra. I found it on Goodreads!! The series is called Extreme Zone by M.C. Sumner. The first book is Night Terrors.

Answer (score -2):

Any idea when you read it. Well it might be Lachlan Fox by James Phelan.

Comment: It would help if you provide some detail as to how that book matches what she's looking for.